# Ends of topological spaces. Why independent of choice of ascending sequence of compact subsets?

Tags: compactifications, at.algebraic-topology, infinite-sequences, path-connected, limits-and-convergence

Quoting from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology):

"Let X be a topological space, and suppose that

K<sub>1</sub> ⊂ K<sub>2</sub> ⊂ K<sub>3</sub> ⊂ · · ·

is an ascending sequence of compact subsets of X whose interiors cover X. Then X has one end for every sequence

U<sub>1</sub> ⊃ U<sub>2</sub> ⊃ U<sub>3</sub> ⊃ · · ·

where each U<sub>n</sub> is a connected component of X \ K<sub>n</sub>. The number of ends does not depend of the specific sequence {K<sub>i</sub>} of compact sets;  in fact, there is a natural bijection between the sets of ends associated with any two such sequences."

How does one prove that the number of ends does not depend on the specific sequence of {K<sub>i</sub>} of compact sets?

An expository proof for a relatively neophyte math student (no category theory...) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider your tags.

Comment: Consider $invlim_{K \subset X} \pi_0 (X-K)$, where $K$ ranges through all compact sets, ordered by inclusion. An exhaustion $K_1 \subset K_2 ...$ as in wikipedias definition is a final sub-poset of the poset of all compact subsets, thus $invlim_{K \subset X} \pi_0 (X-K) \to invlim_n \pi_0 (X-K_n)$ is a bijection. An element in the target is nothing but an end of $X$. Given two compact exhaustions, you combine the two bijections obtained in this way. Admittedly, this is a bit categorical, but wringing out the categories is an exercise with inverse limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main point is this.  Let $(L_k)_{k=0}^\infty$ be another increasing sequence of compact sets whose interiors cover $X$.  Each $X_n$ is compact and contained in the union of the sets $\text{int}(L_k)$, so it is contained in some finite union of these open sets.  As the sets $\text{int}(L_k)$ are nested, it follows that $K_n\subseteq\text{int}(L_{k_n})\subseteq L_{k_n}$ for some index $k_n$.  Moreover, we can assume that $k_n < k_{n+1}$.  Similarly, there is an increasing sequence of indices $n_k$ such that $L_k\subseteq\text{int}(K_{n_k})\subseteq K_{n_k}$ for all $k$.   Now each component of $X\setminus L_{k_n}$ is contained in a unique component of $X\setminus K_n$, and each component of $X\setminus K_{n_k}$ is contained in a unique component of $X\setminus L_k$.  This gives maps $\pi_0(X\setminus L_{k_n})\to\pi_0(X\setminus K_n)$ and $\pi_0(X\setminus K_{n_k})\to\pi_0(X\setminus L_k)$, which can be assembled to give a bijection between the set of ends defined using $K_{*}$ and the set of ends defined using $L_{*}$.

Comment: Thanks, but, and sorry for being so stupid, it still isn't quite clear for me. I can't see why we can assume that  $k_n< k_{n+1}$. Why cannot, or must not, $k_n≤ k_{n+1}$? And therefore, each component of $X\setminus L_{k_n}$ is *not* contained in a *unique* component of $X\setminus K_{n}$, and vice versa?

Comment: The main property that you need for $k_{n+1}$ is that $K_{n+1}\subseteq\text{int}(L_{k_{n+1}})$.  If there exists a value of $k_{n+1}$ with this property, then any larger value will also have the property.  Thus, if the first $k_{n+1}$ that we thought of was not strictly larger than $k_n$, we could just choose to make it bigger.

Comment: Thank you, I realize now that I had assumed $k_{n}$ to be minimal for each $n$ such that $K_{n}\subseteq\text{int}(L_{k_{n}})$. Being new to typology, most are the details a latent risk for misconception, I suppose.

Answer (score 14):

Neil has already given adequate reply; this answer is partly for Simon, and partly for those who *do* like category theory, and realize that its purpose is to make life simpler, not more complicated!

First, IMHO that's not a very good definition in the wikipedia article. A better definition is given in Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Volume I*, page 30: an **end** of a non-compact topological space $X$ is a function $e$ which assigns to each compact subset $K \subset X$ a nonempty component $e(K)$ of the complement $X - K$, in such a way that $K \subset K'$ implies $e(K') \subset e(K)$. This way of putting it circumvents having to *choose* a covering by interiors of compact sets at the outset, and then requiring a lemma that shows independence of choice.

In categorical language, the set of ends of $X$ is the inverse limit of sets

$$\lim_{K \subset X} \pi_0(X - K)$$

where $K$ ranges over compact subsets.

Anyway, in answer to the question, the point is that any sequence of compact subsets whose interiors cover $X$ is cofinal in the directed set of all compact subsets. (A partially ordered set is *directed* if it is nonempty and if any two elements have an upper bound. A subset is *cofinal* if any element in the partial order is bounded above by an element in the subset.)

The point then is that the limit over a directed set is isomorphic to the limit over a cofinal subset (with partial order inherited from the order of the directed set): in the present case, the sequence $K_j$ is cofinal, and the map given by restriction

$$\lim_{K} \pi_0(X - K) \to \lim_j \pi_0(X - K_j)$$

is a bijection. The inverse function takes a sequence of components $C_j$, and assigns to it the function whose value at $K$ is the unique component of $X - K$ which contains $C_j$, where $K_j$ is any compact subset containing $K$. This doesn't depend on $j$, and it is routine to show this does give the inverse function, according to what Neil has already explained.

But it is really just a special case of a much more general argument about cofinal functors; see Categories for the Working Mathematician, page 217, for a rather more general statement.